# SSRS: Execution cannot be found

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, windows-sbs

I've got a Windows SBS 2008 64 bit Box with SQL 2005 64bit on it.  SQL itself runs amazingly well - nice and fast.

SSRS though is giving me headaches.  I ran the install as normal, configured the windows service to run under its own account and the web service to run as NT Authority\Network Service.

When I try to run the reports though (through internet explorer) i get the following error:

> Execution '< guid >' cannot be found.

Looking at the logs it tells me that the NT Authority\Network Service is not found in the database.

I've added the user to the database permissions but am running out of ideas of what else to try now.

I've been googling for two days but nothing concrete has come up.  I know its not strictly programming related please dont downvote for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately none of these were the correct answers.  I had to create an SPN for the machine so that it would work correctly.

SetSPN –A MSSQLSvc/.:1433

As described in [this KB article (909801)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909801)

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to give the NT Authority\Network Service rights to the database.

Comment: Thanks...need to post my answer...turns out an SPN was missing for the machine account so it couldn't delegate properly.  Unfortunately Windows 2008 makes things a lot harder to get working!

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a non-english Operation System?

For some reasons, the account name of "NT Authority\Network Service" has been localized in other languages.
Sadly, a lot of programs have the account name hard coded to the english name, and won't find the Network Service when running on foreign versions of Windows.